SocketIO Port not exposed in AWS Elastic Beanstalk
I have implemented a flask Application, that hosts a socket server.
But I am not able to connect to socket when deployed on Elastic Beanstalk.
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room,send
import json
def configure_socket_events(socketio: SocketIO):
    @socketio.on('connect')
    def handle_connect():
        print(f"Client connected")
    @socketio.on('disconnect')
    def handle_disconnect():
        print(f"Client disconnected: ")
    @socketio.on('join')
    def handle_join(data):
        room_id = data
        join_room(room_id)
        print(f"User  joined room {room_id}")
    @socketio.on('leave')
    def handle_leave(data):
        room_id = data
        leave_room(room_id)
        print(f"User left room {room_id}")
    @socketio.on('send_message')
    def handle_message(data):
        data = json.loads(data)
        print(type(data))
        message = data.get("message")
        is_image = data.get("is_image")
        timestamp = data.get("timestamp")
        user_id = data.get("user_id")
        image = data.get("image")
        data["is_deleted"]=False
        print("Message is ,",message)
        # print("Message Recieved",message)
        emit('message_recieved',json.dumps(data) ,broadcast=True,json=True)
    @socketio.on('delete_message')
    def handle_message(data):
        print(type(data))
        data=json.loads(data)
        messageId = data.get("message_id")
        emit('message_deleted',json.dumps(data) ,broadcast=True,json=True)
    @socketio.on('block_chat')
    def disable_chat(data):
        emit('chat_blocked',json.dumps(data) ,broadcast=True,json=True)
    @socketio.on('unblock_chat')
    def disable_chat(data):
        emit('chat_unblocked',json.dumps(data) ,broadcast=True,json=True)

Imported in init.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
socketio = SocketIO(cors_allowed_origins="*")
def create_app(config_file='config.py'):
    app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/fx_app/media', static_folder='media')
    CORS(app, resources={r"/socket.io/*": {"origins": "*"}})
    app.config.from_pyfile(config_file)
    with app.app_context():
        socketio.init_app(app)  # Initialize Socket.IO
        # Import socket events
        from .socket_events import configure_socket_events
        configure_socket_events(socketio)
        return app

And app.py is as follows :
from fx_app import create_app
app = create_app()

@app.route('/hello_world')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8081, debug=True,load_dotenv=True)

Now, On local machine, it is working fine, i.e. Connection from SocketIO playground is being made correctly.
But When I deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk, the socket is not able to connect.
One Reason that I found is that flask is being hosted on port 8081 and eventlet is on port 8000 when I checked Logs.
app.config in .ebextentsions
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi_custom.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}


packages: 
    yum:
        python3-devel: [] 
        gcc: [] 
        gawk: []
        polkit: []
        gcc-c++: []
        make: []

Procfile
web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 app:app

The server is deployed correctly on Elastic Beanstalk i.e. /hello_world is accessible. But socket is not being connected.
When explored on internet, and Stack Overflow, I got that I have to disable Proxy. But in Elastic Beanstalk configuration, there is no option to do so. Only I can select between Nginx and Apache
When I tried disabling Proxy in ebextensions like
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:
    ProxyServer: 'none'

I got an error when I deploy to Elastic Beanstalk [Screenshot Attached]
enter image description here
